# Выдает ошибку: AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Tags: python, telebot, pythonanywhere

Написал бота, загрузил на pythonanywhere.com, пишет ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Qwertyus/bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'
```

Модуль устанавливался через команду `pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI`

Код подключения:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
```

Comment: ошибка в коде,  посмотрите правильность написания и существование TeleBot()

Comment: @Дмитрий посмотрите сами https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI   первыйже пример

Comment: У вас рядом с вашим файлом bot.py случайно нет другого файла telebot.py?